# In wordpress, comments, how to show initials intead of full name

Tags: wordpress

I want the user to be able to select if he/she wants to display his full name or his/her initials on posting a comment.

Not for all comments just for the ones he/she selects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code a) shows an input field after 'POST' form submit button that provides the option to show initial letters instead of full name, b) adds a commentmeta field in the database to show the information, and c) retrieves the meta and displays the full name or the initials.

```
/* Add an input field for posting comment form with the switch to show initials instead of full name */
function add_comment_stealth_input_formfield(){
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="stealth_comment" id="stealth_comment" value="0">';
    echo __("I want only my initials to be displayed instead of my name","comments");
}
add_action( 'comment_form', 'add_comment_stealth_input_formfield' );

/*  Hide comment author name */
if( !function_exists("disable_comment_author_links")){
    function abbreviate_authorname_in_comments( $author_link ){

        $sw_initials = get_comment_meta( get_comment_ID(), 'sw_comment_initials',true);

        if ($sw_initials == 1){
            // remove any html tags
            $fullname = strip_tags( $author_link );

            // explode with ' '
            $separate = explode(" ", $fullname);

            // make initials
            $shrt = "";
            foreach ($separate as $w){
                $shrt .= strtoupper($w[0].".");
            }

            // if more than 3 initials then something is wrong. Hide the last ones to be safe
            if (strlen($shrt) > 6)
                $shrt = substr($shrt, 0, 6);

            return $shrt;
        } else {
            return $author_link;
        }
    }
    add_filter( 'get_comment_author_link', 'abbreviate_authorname_in_comments' );
}

/* add a comment meta per comment */
function add_comment_field_initials_sw( $comment_id ) {
    $isChecked = is_null($_REQUEST['stealth_comment']) ? 0:1;
    add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'sw_comment_initials', $isChecked );
}
add_action( 'comment_post', 'add_comment_field_initials_sw' );
```